# vba change text in a bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am updating a word document using text in an excel spreadsheet.

I understand from reading posts that if you change the text in a bookmark using bookmark.text = "xx" this deletes the bookmark and you have to add it back in. However I am having trouble doing this because I can't set the range for the bookmark to add back.

I tried using the code below but get the run time error 13 - Type mismatch. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub ChangeBMtext()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ARange As Range

    FileName = "C:\Drafts\Quick Test"

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)

    If WordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("InDocText") Then
        Set ARange = WordDoc.Bookmarks("InDocText").Range
        WordDoc.Bookmarks("InDocText").Range.Text = "add this text"
        WordDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="InDocText", Range:=ARange
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the error comes at the lien where I try to set ARange = ...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer elsewhere. This code works perfectly:

Sub ChangeBMtext()

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim strBMName As String
Dim objBMRange As Object

FileName = "C:\Drafts\Quick Test"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)

If WordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("InDocText") Then
    strBMName = "InDocText"
    Set objBMRange = WordDoc.Bookmarks(strBMName).Range
    objBMRange.Text = "add this text"
    WordDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=strBMName, Range:=objBMRange
    Set objBMRange = Nothing
End If
```

End Sub